# HTTP error 500 (php html) forces me to change IP

Tags: php, http, server

I'm completely stuck trying to debug a problem i have been having a long time.

I cannot replicate the cause, however, it seems after some time my website will just return a `500` HTTP return status code.

My fix is having to use a VPN to change IP address *(or wait sometimes hours)* and then everything is fine until it happens again. Sometimes it will last hours, days or minutes. It is on any page and completely random.

My server logs doesn't show anything, and I have no idea where to start.

I tried removing my htaccess and it also only seems to happen when logged in or having an active session.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah a `500` error is not very helpful - since the question is tagged PHP, have you [enabled error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/5120832)?

Comment: yes, i have been through many pages and no errors are showing up apart from an undefined variable here and there that i have since fixed. I have no idea where to start, i contacted my hosting provider and they said they could not see anything.

Comment: use a debugging tool, i would suggest using Whoops for php, it should show you detailed error and where it all started. `500` is not enough for us to find where is the problem

Comment: Are you sure your host isn't blocking your IP address for some reason?